# convert 2d array with varied length into database table

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following array in PHP:

```
$my_neighbor_lists = array(
1=> array(3351=>0.033901347),
2=> array(3264=>0.032575596, 3471=>0.026325627),
3=> array(3467=>0.042802818),
4=> array(3309=>0.039961922999999996, 3469=>0.042992210999999995),
5=> array(3315=>0.068939052, 3316=>0.027272592, 3469=>0.028977129),
6=> array(3305=>0.051704289, 3309=>0.032386203),
7=> array(3267=>0.118181232, 3354=>0.088067745, 3424=>0.077840523, 3437=>0.119696376),
8=> array(3302=>0.124052415, 3467=>0.040151316),
9=> array(3305=>0.040908888, 3306=>0.028030164, 3465=>0.095643465),
10=> array(3271=>0.051704289, 3472=>0.048105822),
11=> array(3347=>0.051704289, 3468=>0.049620965999999996),
12=> array(3310=>0.044886141, 3315=>0.044886141),
13=> array(3271=>0.107764617, 3354=>0.166287054, 3364=>0.15927951299999998, 6729=>0.128219061));
```

I want to be moving this to a database. Currently the way I am using this array is by traversing through the key:

```
foreach ($my_neighbor_lists[$i] as $j => $step)
           $g[$j] = $g[$i] + ($step /.0000832154);
```

If I changed this to a db, how would I change this code? I am guessing it's using PDO, but I am fairly new with PDO.

Comment: What on earth is the `/ .0000832154` for?

Comment: fairly simple, for the pdo part you'll find tons of turorials/questions_answers , for the table part i would suggest a table with 4 columns ( 1 id_row primary key autoincrement, 2 id_neighbor int, 3 neighbor_key int, neighbor_value ), then take the second array from you're example would sit on 2 rows in the table ...

Comment: it's just some random number that I create to illustrate I will be using $step inside the array

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you serialize your array ?

I would serialize it using json_encode (and deserialize it using json_decode)

Comment: becouse then you can't "search" thru the neighbor's list can you ? you'd have to get all the results and then ... what if you have 1mil entryes ? doesn't sound like a good ideea anymore .

Comment: Of course you can't search in a serialized version. That was not my goal. Actually I was just trying to answer the question.

Comment: you're answers shouldn't be just "patches for the problem now and we'll se how it will work in the future ( if it will work )". You'll be amezed how faster and easyer programming is if you plan ahead and follow so called "best practices"

Answer (score 0):

Or use [mongodb](http://www.mongodb.org/)
[Extension for php](http://php.net/mongo)